# Определение, содержит ли ввод пользователя цифры

Tags: javascript

Хочу сделать проверку на введённые символы

```
function Loc() {
    var re = /\d/ig;
    var inp = prompt("Введите своё имя", '')
    if(inp.match(re) && inp=='') {
        alert("Неверный ввод!");
        return;
    }
    else {alert(inp+', адрес вашего документа - '+location.hostname);}
}
```

Как видно, мне нужно, чтобы при попытке ввести числа вместо букв, он выкидывал алерт с неверным вводом.

На деле, он это условие тупо игнорит, и выводит алерт с inp и адресом документа. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `(inp.match(re) && inp=='')` -> `(inp.match(re) || inp=='')`, `"Невреный ввод!"` -> `"Неверный ввод!"`

Answer (score 1):

`if(inp.match(re) && inp=='')`

Вы проверяете, что inp содержит цифры И *одновременно с этим* абсолютно пуст.
так быть не может. Может вы хотели написать *ИЛИ*:

`if(inp.match(re) || inp=='')`